# C# for-loop declaring variables

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF program, I have an area of C# code that is quite repetitive, and it looks like this:

```
labelFirst = EnglishPicker.SelectedColorText.Substring(0, 1);
labelLast = EnglishPicker.SelectedColorText.Substring(3, 6);
label = labelFirst + labelLast;
UpdateSetting("English", label);
labelFirst = PhotographyPicker.SelectedColorText.Substring(0, 1);
labelLast = PhotographyPicker.SelectedColorText.Substring(3, 6);
label = labelFirst + labelLast;
UpdateSetting("Photography", label);
```

So I had a thought, is it possible to put this in a for loop something like this:

```
string[] names = {"English","Photography"};
foreach (string name in names)
{
    labelFirst = (name +"Picker").SelectedColorText.Substring(0, 1);
}
```

**Solution for those seeking help**
Using a SharedMethod, I was able to shorten the code down as EnglishPicker and PhotographyPicker are the same class. Code:

```
private void GetPickerLabel(PickerClass picker){
    labelFirst = picker.SelectedColorText.Substring(0,1);
    labelLast = picker.SelectedColorText.Substring(3,6);
    return labelFirst + labelLast;
}

UpdateSetting("English",GetPickerLabel(EnglishPicker));
UpdateSetting("Photography",GetPickerLabel(PhotographyPicker));
```

Thanks for those who helped me. :)

Comment: Are `EnglishPicker` and `PhotographyPicker` static classes or are they  properties ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a reflection-based solution, I would simply refactor the code to move the shared code in a separate method.

Example:

```
SharedMethod(EnglishPicker, "English");
SharedMethod(PhotographyPicker, "Photography");

// ...

private void SharedMethod(PickerClass picker, string settingName)
{
    var labelFirst = picker.SelectedColorText.Substring(0, 1);
    var labelLast = picker.SelectedColorText.Substring(3, 6);
    var label = labelFirst + labelLast;
    UpdateSetting(settingName, label);
}
```

Comment: It won't work if `EnglishPicker` and `PhotographyPicker` are two different types. If that's not the case, then this approach would be the best.

Comment: Worked like a charm :) The EnglishPicker and PhotographyPicker are the names of 2 elements with the same class. A few minor changes and it was fixed. Thanks heaps

Answer (score 3):

I think you almost nailed the simplest approach to this in your question, but using strings to refer to the pickers can break at run-time.

Try this instead:

```
Picker[] pickers = { EnglishPicker, PhotographyPicker};
foreach (Picker picker in pickers)
{
    labelFirst = picker.SelectedColorText.Substring(0, 1);
}
```

The advantage here is that you have compile-time correctness and you can explicitly include or exclude any pickers you like.

It would be easy to turn the control back into text via the `.Name` property to get the setting updated.

Answer (score 2):

Providing `EnglishPicker` and `PhotographyPicker` are properties:

You can use [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<string> names = new [] { "English", "Photography" };
foreach (string name in names)
{
     // Build the property name
     string propertyName = String.Concat(name, "Picker");

     // Get Picker instance by locating the correct property
     object picker = this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this);

     // Get the SelectedColorText value from that instance
     string colorText = (string) picker.GetType().GetProperty("SelectedColorText").GetValue(picker);

     string first = colorText.Substring(0, 1);
     string last = colorText.Substring(3, 6);
     string label = String.Concat(first, last);

     // Call UpdateSetting
     UpdateSetting(name, label);
}
```

Flexibility comes with a price.

Everything, from the property lookup to the method invocation will be done in runtime, so **watch out!** It'll compile fine but it might break when you run it.

For instance, if you were to mistype `"Enlgish"` instead of `"English"`, the code would compile perfectly. But, at runtime, the code will try to locate `EnlgishPicker` property and it'll fail.

Also, the above code is not defensive at all.

You should update it to include null checks to avoid potential exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

How about an interface?  No reflection needed at all.  That's what they're for.

```
public interface ISelectedColorContainer {
    string SelectedColorText {get;}
}
```

**An Implementation**

(I have no idea what your classes look like, but that's why we use interfaces!)

```
public class EnglishPickerImplementation:ISelectedColorContainer {
    public string SelectedColorText {get {return "sunflower";}}
}

public class PhotographyPickerImplementation:ISelectedColorContainer {
    public string SelectedColorText {get {return "chartreuse";}}
}
```

So you'd have a function that looks like this:

```
void SomeMethod(){
    ISelectedColorContainer items = new ISelectedColorContainer[] {
      new EnglishPickerImplementation(), new PhotographyPickerImplementation()};
   foreach(var item in items){

    var labelFirst = UpdateSetting(item);
    var labelLast = item.SelectedColorText.Substring(3, 6);
    var label = labelFirst + labelLast;
   }
} 

string UpdateSetting(ISelectedColorContainer input){
     return  input.SelectedColorText.Substring(0, 1);
}
```

Sorry if there are slight syntax errors, I didn't put this in an IDE.

Comment: You should probably give an example implementation.